# Acronym at sentence start: capital or not?

Tags: typography, acronyms, capitalization, small-caps

The recommended way of typesetting acronyms is using small caps, e.g.:

```
This technique is called Remote Procedure Calling or {\scshape rpc}.
```

However, if the acronym occurs at the beginning of the sentence, would you capitalize its first letter or not?

```
{\scshape rpc} is the name of this technique.\\
{\scshape Rpc} is the name of this technique.
```

[image]

Which one would be most appropriate and why?

Comment: In this situation, I suggest: "The name of this technique is RPC." It is a good practice to avoid beginning a sentence with an acronym or an abbreviation. See, for example, http://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/DocAPAPrinciples.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't use capitals in this case. Quoting Hedrick, [*Fine Points of Typographic Usage:*](http://www.nbcs.rutgers.edu/~hedrick/typography/disputed.html)

> What do you do if a sentence starts with an acronym, e.g. "RUCS is
>   great." If you're using small caps, I would set RUCS in small caps.
>   Some people are bothered because this seems to violate the rule about
>   capitalizing the first word.
>
> To understand my answer, you need to realize that small caps are used
>   in two completely different ways.
>
> - In some cases they are used for abbreviations or acronyms, e.g. NATO [typeset in small caps]. In this case the small caps are acting
>     as capital letters that just happen to be smaller than usual.
> - However in some contexts small caps are mixed with full caps. E.g. some people recommend that in bibliographies, the author's name should
>     be in mixed case, with the first letter of each name in full caps and
>     the rest of the name in small caps: CHARLES HEDRICK [typeset with
>     first letter capitalized, rest in small caps]. In this case the small
>     caps are being used as lowercase.
>
> Let's go back to the question of a sentence that starts with an
>   acronym. The problem with using a full cap for the first letter is
>   that by mixing case, it makes it look like the small caps are being
>   used as lowercase. E.g. in "RUCS" if you put R in full caps and the
>   rest in small caps, RUCS [typeset with first letter capitalized, rest
>   in small caps], it looks like a word or name Rucs, not an acronymn. So
>   my rule is:
>
> - If small caps are being used as capitals (e.g. in acronyms or abbreviations), don't change them when you put them at the beginning
>     of a sentence.
> - If small caps are being used as lowercase, then use normal rules for capitalization. Turn the first letter into full caps at the start
>     of a sentence or elsewhere that capitalization is expected.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110858/capitalization-of-biological-abbreviations-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence